# Multiple ranges in one VBA For loop?

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I am a beginner at VBA and am trying to highlight only empty cells in columns N and AA only.  Can there be multiple ranges in one For loop to make this work instead of the following code?

```
Private Sub CommandButton22_Click()
    'HIGHLIGHT
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("N")
        If cell.Value = vbNullString Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next cell

    For Each cell In Range("AA")
        If cell.Value = vbNullString Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If

    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply create a non-continuous range by combining the two range address like the:

```
For Each cell In Range("N:N,AA:AA")

Next
```

But it is more efficient to use the Intersect method to trim the range to the used portion of the worksheet:

```
For Each cell In Intersect(Range("N:N,AA:AA"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If cell.Value = vbNullString Then
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
Next
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  It worked like a dream.  The UsedRange also fixed my null cells not within the data range issue.  I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7):

edited to *join* the `SpecialCells` approach with the benefit of the `UsedRange` as pointed out by Thomas Inzina solution

Use [`SpecialCells()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) method of `Range` object and avoid looping

```
Private Sub CommandButton22_Click()
    'HIGHLIGHT
    Intersect(Union(Range("N:N"), Range("AA:AA")), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use the `Application.Union` method. That returns [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.areas(v=office.11).aspx) / A collection of the areas, or contiguous blocks of cells, within a selection.

The following code works.

```
Private Sub CommandButton22_Click()
'HIGHLIGHT

Dim cell As Range
Dim target As Range

    Set target = Application.Union(ActiveSheet.Range("N:N"), ActiveSheet.Range("AA:AA"))

    For Each area In target.Areas
        For Each cell In area
            If cell.Value = vbNullString Then
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        Next cell
    Next area
End Sub
```

It will color the entire column though. If you just want to color a subset, ex: from rows `10` through `22` in both columns, then change the union line to something like this

`Set target = Application.Union(ActiveSheet.Range("N10:N22"), ActiveSheet.Range("AA10:AA22"))`